# I want to change the background color of Salesforce Lightning List View any one can help?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have created below component using lightning List view-

```
<lightning:listView aura:id="listViewAccounts"
objectApiName="Account"
listName="qwerty__AllAccounts"
rows="10"
showSearchBar="true"
showActionBar="false"
enableInlineEdit="true"
showRowLevelActions="false"
```

/>

But i want to change its background color like attached image.
Qwerty is a namespace of my org...

[image]

Comment: if you want the list view to look like the image it would require lot of work not just background color

Comment: Will you please help me out by that how i would change some code or add some CSS for list to look like image.